# automatocally set 100 % width for a div in bootsrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with twitter bootstrap 3

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-9  ">
   mid left
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 ">
   mid right
</div>
```

how to set `mid left` `col-sm-12` if `mid right` is hidden ?

that is the HTML output after page run (PHP),

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-9  ">
   mid left
</div>
```

I need `col-sm-12` instead of `col-sm-9`.

Comment: explain it. What do you want do??

Comment: can you please explain it in detail

Comment: In your CSS file you would set the width to 100%? Like the above comments suggested. I'm not sure what your trying to do?

Comment: If your PHP code has some condition (if-else) for showing the right column then you can use the same condition to determine if the left column has class col-sm-9 or col-sm-12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12 ">
     mid left
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
     mid right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hidden-xs is ok. but some time mid right div is hidden by php not by screen width

Comment: You mean that `mid right` can be hidden any time using php ? If yes then you have to add/remove class from `mid left` using jquery!!

Answer (score 0):

Do You want to like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
       mid left
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-offset-9 ">
      mid right
   </div>
</div>
```